# Can't Undo Images in tkinter text field

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a text field in tkinter and set some of its attributes.

```
content_text = Text(root, wrap='word',font=Font, undo=True, autoseparators =True, maxundo=-1)
content_text.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
```

I have also created a function for inserting images in text area.

```
def insertImage():
    select_image = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select your image",
                                              filetypes=[("Image Files", "*.png"), ("Image Files", "*.jpg")])
    if select_image:
        imagelist.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=select_image))
        content_text.image_create(END, image=imagelist[-1])
```

But whenever I tried to undo using `Ctrl` + `Z` it only undo text but not my inserted images.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and what will be the solution for this.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? After you opened the image and hit ```Ctrl + Z``` you want the image to disappear?

Comment: @Itsjul1an yes I want that my images should also get disappear after I press `Ctrl+Z`

Comment: as for me `Ctrl + Z` in `Text` could be created only to work with text. And it would need to build all from scratch (if it is even possible)